# Clustered index data access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to understand how SQL Server access data from the clustered index. My understanding is when the table has a clustered index SQL should be able to seek into the single page that holds the record using the seek predicate.

However, my test showing me when the query is executed it loads a few more data pages.

### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE t2(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,col2 VARCHAR(500),col3 VARCHAR(500));

INSERT INTO [dbo].[t2]([col2],[col3])
SELECT TOP 10010 REPLICATE('z',490),REPLICATE('*',490)
FROM sys.all_columns c1,
     sys.all_columns c2
```

The following query

```
select *
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id(N'dbo.t2'),DEFAULT,null,'DETAILED');
```

shows the output as

[image]

I then cleared the cache with

```
CHECKPOINT 

GO

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

And ran the following `SELECT` seeking into a single row

```
SELECT  [fplc].*,[t2].[col3] FROM [dbo].[t2] AS [t2] 
CROSS APPLY sys.[fn_PhysLocCracker](%%physloc%%) AS [fplc]
WHERE id=4582
```

The above query tells me the record is located on the page 1061

I use the code below check how many pages have been loaded into the buffer to get the result of my SELECT

```
SELECT buffers.* FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors  buffers
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
    ON au.[allocation_unit_id] = buffers.[allocation_unit_id]
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON au.[container_id] = p.[partition_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON i.[index_id] = p.[index_id] AND p.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
WHERE p.[object_id] > 100
and [database_id] = DB_ID () AND i.[object_id]=OBJECT_ID('t2')
 ORDER BY [page_level] desc
```

Why SQL is loading all the pages marked in green? Are the pages loaded by READ AHEAD ?
[image]

Comment: If the table is small, it might decide to scan the table as opposed to seeking because it would be faster.

Comment: @TonyHinkle - That is often stated but I've never seen SQL Server decide to convert a seekable predicate on a covering index to a scan on the same index regardless if the table has no rows at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in [The Read Ahead that doesn’t count as Read Ahead](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ialonso/2011/12/09/the-read-ahead-that-doesnt-count-as-read-ahead/)

> what I wanted to talk about in this post, was another prefetching
>   mechanism that can be triggered by any query when SQL is running any
>   of the editions considered Enterprise (i.e. Developer, Evaluation, and
>   Enterprise itself). The aim of this optimization is to warm up the
>   cache as quickly as possible. **To do so, the buffer pool converts any
>   request to read a single page from disk into a request that will read
>   the whole extent containing the page initially requested.**

In your case you ran this after clearing the buffer cache with `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`. So SQL Server is in the state that it would try and warm up the cache quickly.

You needed to read three pages to perform the seek (one at each level of the index). These were pages `1111`, `1382` and `1061`.

So you ended up bringing in three entire extents with page numbers `1056 - 1063`, `1104 - 1111` and `1376 - 1383`.

If you do the same experiment against some other SKU than mentioned in the quote (and traceflag 840 is not enabled) you should see your expected three pages (below was against Express LocalDB)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin.. I appreciate your support. 

I have another question and apologies if its a dumb question. So,SQL did additional pages to warm-up the cache. If the table has ROW_OVERFLOW type data, wouldn't this additional read cause unnecessary IO and cost memory?

Comment: It didn't do additional reads. It just did 64KB reads instead of 8KB reads. It only does this ramp up when it is using less memory than target. With row overflow pages reading them in speculatively could still be useful. They may never get used and eventually get evicted under the LRU policy but that is the same for the data pages that are brought in speculatively.